# What does it mean to be unregistered?

Tags: discussion, users

When I clicked on a [user name](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/11667/ar-ar-ar) in a question just now, it says "Unregistered".

What does this mean?  If the user has a profile, and their name is showing up in the question, it seems to me they are registered.  So why does it say "Unregistered"?  How did their status become that way?

[image]

Comment: A lot of time these questions that are "generic" functionality questions can be answered by searching meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/unregistered-user
 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account

Comment: @W5VO Thanks.  I only searched the meta for this site and didn't think of looking at meta.stackoverflow.com.  I knew there were lots of users with names like user12345 but I didn't realize a user could have a chosen name (e.g. AR AR AR), and reputation and badges (like in the example above) and still be unregistered.  The explanation you linked to re cookies vs registration clears that up.

Comment: [What does 'unregistered' mean on user profiles?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3211/36448)

Answer (score 1):

> They haven't registered themselves on the site by OpenID. They are logged in with a long living cookie tied to a specific PC/webbrowser. They won't be able to login using the same account on other PCs/webbrowsers.

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68524/unregistered-user)